# How to find the number of integers of the form $\overline{a_7a_6a_5...a_1}$ where $\forall i,$ $a_i\leq a_{i+1}$ and $a_7 \neq 0$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, solution-verification

I need to find  find the number of integers of the form $\overline{a_7a_6a_5...a_1}$ where $\forall i,$ $a_i\leq a_{i+1}$ and $a_7\neq0$

In one of my previous exercises I proved that, if you move only either right or up every turn, from the point $(0,0)$ to the point $(m,n)$ there are $\binom{m+n}{n}$ ways to get there.

So lets imagine the same thing for the numbers. If we start in $(1,0)$ as if we fixed $a_7=1$, there will be $\binom{7+0}{0}$ ways to reach $(7,1)$ (assuming that we suppose $(1,0)$ to be $(0,0)$ for the formula to work) which corresponds to the last digit being 1.

Then we proceed the same way for every other last digit possible, giving us $$\sum_{i=0}^{8}\binom{7+i}{i}$$
We proceed the same way for every possible first digit, which gives us the final formula of 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{9}\sum_{i=0}^{9-j}\binom{7+i}{i}
$$
This is what I have tried so far solving this problem. What am I asking here is a feedback on my reasoning, to either confirm that my logic in approaching this exercise is correct or did I make a mistake somewhere.

Any alternate solution would be welcomed as well.

Comment: Can the first digit be $0$?

Comment: If the first digit can be $0$, then the answer is the same as the number of integer solutions $x_i\ge 0$ to $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_8=9$ (by taking $a_i=x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_i$).  If the first digit can't be $0$, you just need to subtract the answer from the previous calculation by $1$.

Comment: First digit cannot be $0
$

Comment: @WETutorialSchool you meant $x_1+x_2+...+x_7=9$ I suppose? Just to make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: I do mean $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_8=9$, which is equivalent to $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_7\le 9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the digits of your number (with multiplicity), you know your number, because the digits in your number are increasing (or staying the same) from the single digit.

So the question becomes: In how many ways can you select 7 digits, with possible repetition, from the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$?

That's a standard combinatorial question, usually called "combinations with repetition". Wikipedia has a long [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) about combinations, including formulas and proofs. In  this case, the answer is, as there are 10 digits

$${10+7-1 \choose 7}={16 \choose 7}= 11440.$$

But wait, there was an additional condition in the problem, $a_7$ can't be zero! But since $\forall 1 \le i \le 6$ we have $a_i \le a_{i+1}$, this requires all $a_i$ to be zero. So this is just $1$ solution of the ones calculated above, so the answer to your problem is:

There are ${16 \choose 7}-1=11439$ such $7$-digit numbers.

Comment: It makes sense. But there is one thing I cannot understand. How does that that approach garantees that all of the numbers are such as every digit is less than the previous from left to the right. I'm really struggling with understanding combinatorics, so it doesnt click for me.

Comment: @Dknot Let's visualize this by drawing digits from an urn and after each draw the digit is noted down but put back (so it can be redrawn again). I get 3,9,4,3,0,6,6 in that order. How many of "your" numbers can you make from that? What about 6,3,3,6,9,4,0 (same digits, just reordered)? How many can you make from that draw and how are they releated to the ones from my first example?

Comment: I can make $4$ for each of the examples, but they will all be just repetitions of each other

Comment: It somewhat reminds me of the formula for the rearrangements with repetitions, where we have $n$ objects, some of them repeating and then we have $\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!...n_i!}$. But it is somewhat different for my case as for every unique set of digits I can only make 1 number

Comment: Okay, I think I finally figured out how to use the formula, on my way to understanding the proof. Thank you

Comment: @Dknot In my comment above, the idea is that in both cases, there is only **one** number that can be generated: 9664330. If you have the digits, your $a_i \le a_{i+1}$ condition makes sure there is one and only one number that has those digits and fullfills your condition.